# How to decide which entity should be the owner of relation

Tags: java, many-to-many, entity

Like in a topic. How to decide which entity should be the owner of relation. I have two entity and want to create mantToMany relation between. I hvae class teams and persons. One person can be in many teams, and many teams can have many person. But my question is how to decide in which entity should i create @jointable.

Comment: I Believe it doesn't matter. You annotate with JoinTable in both entities with the only difference that the joinColumn and inverseColumns are swapped.

Comment: So i decide to mark owner (add @jointable) in person class. I decide becouse i found information that i should think on which entity i make more delete create operation. I think that i make more operation on person entity.

Comment: Ok that sounds reasonable,